# PHP Sessions and Reviewing of forms

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 questions.

I am creating an Application Form for a school using PHP and MySql.

I have my forms done and everything gets entered into a MySql database.

During Step 1, the user enters an Identity Number of the student applying at the school. This Identity number is used to identify the student in all tables of the database.

**Question 1:**
How can I create a php session or something, to hold the Identity Number throughout the whole application process (the process is over a few PHP pages, and not on a single page - or should it be a single page?) so that when we get to the last step of the application process, the Identity Number will be kept in order to search for the record in the database (question 2)

**Question 2:**
After doing question 1 above, how can I retrieve the information based on the Identity Number (primary key) and show all the data of that student for reviewing on the last step of the process?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's a lot easier to help you complete your code rather than build it from scratch. Do you have a starting point that we can work off of?

Answer (score 2):

**Ans of question 1:**
You can set session as below which you can access on all the pages

```
$_SESSION['StudentID'] = '500'; //vale can be from DB or as required
```

**Ans of question 2:** You can retrieve/use session value as below:

```
echo $studenID = $_SESSION['StudentID'];
```

To access session variables session should be started using session_start(); function in PHP

Answer (score 1):

1) On any page where you want to access the session variables:

```
session_start();
```

To set a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['identityNumber'] = $identityNumber;
```

And let's say that you've got a table for the form called `formInfo` where `identityNumber` is the primary key and already have a database connection called `$mysqli`. Then at each stage in the form

```
$query = "UPDATE formInfo SET var1 = $var1, var2 = $var2 
          WHERE identityNumber = {$_SESSION['identityNumber']}";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

where `$var1` & `var2` are values from your form.

2) Then to get all that form data in the last steps,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM formInfo 
          WHERE identityNumber = {$_SESSION['identityNumber']}";
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
```

changing `*` to whichever variables your interested in. `$row` will be 
an associative array of your form, e.g. like `$row['var1']`.